# Prevent power plan from changing when plugging in / unplugging laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-10, power-management

I have a custom power plan on my laptop and I Enable it by doing:
  Right Click battery icon > Power options > select 'My Custom Plan 1' > close the window

Then I plug my laptop in, go back to Power Options > and it is changed to 'Balanced'. So I select 'My Custom Plan 1' and close the window.

Then I unplug the laptop > go to power options > it is changed back to 'Balanced' yet again.

So, how can I stop the power plan from automatically switching when I plug in or unplug my laptop?

**Laptop:** It is an Acer Aspire series 5733, model PEW71. Originally had Windows 7, but got free upgrade to Win10
**Note:** As far as I know, there are no third-party programs running that do anything with the power settings. I have [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) installed, but I don't think it does anything with the power plans.

Comment: Why don't you just tweak 'Balanced' to do what you want it to do?

Comment: Good point. I'll probably do that. I'm still curious if there's an actual solution to the auto-changing, though.